# html selected disabled

Tags: html

I'm having trouble displaying the first option in a select element like this: http://jsfiddle.net/L6h9Q/

I want the first option tag to work as a placeholder but the second one is displayed first by default.

Comment: because you have disable the first option. Is this your requirement to disable the first option?

Comment: Is there any way to get around this? Would like to use the disabled option to work as a placeholder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add `selected="selected"` attribute to the first option to put it on default.

Answer (score 1):

A workaround: http://jsfiddle.net/L6h9Q/2/

Essential part:

1. Add `required` to `select`;
2. Use `select:invalid` to make the color gray;
3. use `option:first-child` to make the first option gray.

Downside: works only on HTML5/CSS3 supported browsers.

---

**Edit**:

Inspired by @Russell, here's a (somewhat) better solution: http://jsfiddle.net/L6h9Q/3/

Answer (score 1):

Disabled items (by definition) cannot be selected.  The item that is shown when the page is loaded is indeed selected.

The canonical way around this using plain JS and HTML is to leave that option enabled, then validate your form result upon submission (client- and server-side).  If the user has selected the placeholder option ("City..." in your case), then let them know that they have made an invalid selection.

Answer (score 0):

yes because It will show only enabled values first and then disabled values